# Unable to get a user token in a remote session

Tags: winapi, token

*So I'd like to LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress wtsapi32.dll to call WTSQueryUserToken() in my server with Windows Server 2008.
The file can be explicitly loaded without problems when I actually **walk to** the server and execute this program.
However, when I Mstsc.exe to access to my server and do the same thing, it ends up GetProcAddress() failing with the error code 2 from GetLastError().
wtsapi32.dll does have things to do with Remote Desktop Service APIs but I have no idea how to trace this problem.
Any hints will be truly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.*

**EDIT:**

It turned out that I got another thinking coming about what I am really having a trouble with.

So wtsapi32.dll is loaded in any case, even when I Mstsc.exe my server.

The real problem is that WTSQueryUserToken() always fails with FALSE returned **ONLY** when I Mstsc.exe the server. My server operating system is Windows Server 2008. WTSQueryUserToken() in my desktop, which uses Windows 7, works fine.

My code goes here.

```
HANDLE hTokenImperson = nullptr;

HMODULE hModWtsapi32 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("wtsapi32.dll"));
HMODULE hModKernel32 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
auto lpfnWTSQueryUserToken = reinterpret_cast<bool(*)(ULONG, PHANDLE)>(GetProcAddress(hModWtsapi32, "WTSQueryUserToken"));
auto lpfnWTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId = reinterpret_cast<DWORD(*)(void)>(GetProcAddress(hModKernel32, "WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId"));

// dwSessionId is not 0.
dwSessionId = lpfnWTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(); 

// FALSE returns only when I do mstsc.exe.
// Works well when I walk to my server and execute this application.
lpfnWTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &hTokenImperson)
```

I've renamed my question's title since it didn't have to do anything with what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show code. Error code 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and `GetProcAddress` won't ever set that error code. Perhaps your error checking code is wrong. Perhaps it's the `LoadLibrary` that fails. But without code we cannot help.

Comment: Show us you LoadLibrary code.

Comment: Taking a good nap, figured out this wasn't fully showing what I am getting so I edited. Thanks for all of your replies of course.

Comment: I have just started looking at this stuff myself, but don't flame me if I ask a dumb question: would it be not working because you are asking for SessionId of the ActiveConsole, and not that of a remote session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` returns the session that is currently attached to the physical console ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). 
If you need to get a token for a remote session, you could call [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first and look for the active session.

```
BOOL WTSEnumerateSessions(
  _In_   HANDLE hServer,
  _In_   DWORD Reserved,
  _In_   DWORD Version,
  _Out_  PWTS_SESSION_INFO *ppSessionInfo, // <------
  _Out_  DWORD *pCount
);
```

Check the *State* of `PWTS_SESSION_INFO` structure.

After you get session ID for an active session, call `WTSQueryUserToken` to get the access token.